# When I peer two VPCs in different regions does the traffic traverse through the public internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm looking for various ways to connect two VPCs in different regions without traversing the traffic through public internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not go over public internet. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html):

> Traffic always stays on the global AWS backbone, and **never traverses the public internet**, which reduces threats, such as common exploits, and DDoS attacks.